# Why are polysaccharides non-reducing sugars?

Tags: carbohydrates

My book says that polysaccharides are non-reducing sugars, and they form of condensation of >6 molecules of monosaccharides. The condensation involves the carbonyl groups of the sugars, **leaving only one free carbonyl group at the end of a big molecule.**

My question is: since there is one free carbonyl group why aren't polysaccharides reducing sugars?!

Comment: This question is better suited over at chemistry.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/63045/why-is-maltose-a-reducing-sugar-but-not-sucrose-even-though-theyre-both-disacc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For polysaccharides made with only glucose (starch, cellulose, glycogen, etc), only 1 unit can be reduced from hundreds, thousands or tens of thousands of units. With the same mass of dextrose and starch, the amount reduced for starch is 1/100, 1/1000 or 1/10000 the amount for dextrose. This is usually below the detection limit for most ways of detecting the reaction.